# Не показываются кнопки vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу бота на Python, использую библиотеку vk_api
Столкнулся с проблемой - кнопки не показываются у пользователя (клавиатура бота). Подумал, что проблема в том, что я не включил возможности ботов в настройках группы VK, но после их включения кнопки всё равно не работают.
Что можно сделать и в чём может быть проблема?

```
import random
import time

import sqlite3

import vk_api
from vk_api import keyboard
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id": user_id, "message": message, "random_id":random.randint(1000000, 9000000000000)})

token = "token_for_vk_group"
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
    #SE FUNCS
vkkeyboard = keyboard.VkKeyboard(one_time=False)
data = []
existcheck = []
allusers = []


sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
sqlite_cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
sqlite_cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS'users' ( 'vkid' text );""")
for event in longpoll.listen():
   if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
      existcheck = sqlite_cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM users WHERE vkid = ? ;""" , [event.user_id]).fetchone() or []
      if len(existcheck) > 0:
            write_msg(event.user_id, "Вы уже зарегистрировались")
            vkkeyboard.add_line()
            vkkeyboard.add_button("Картошка!", color='secondary', )


      if len(existcheck) == 0:
            sqlite_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users (vkid) VALUES (?);""", [event.user_id])    
            sqlite_connection.commit()
            write_msg(event.user_id, "Вы зарегистрировались")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы [не передавали `vkkeyboard` в сообщении](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/a4d26e2a6f9d137c55f26b296305636b6a19344a/examples/keyboard.py#L34)

Поменял функцию и явно передаю клавиатуру, пример:

```
def write_msg(user_id, message, keyboard=None):
    vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id": user_id, "message": message, "keyboard": keyboard, "random_id": random.randint(1000000, 9000000000000)})

...

vkkeyboard = keyboard.VkKeyboard(one_time=False)
vkkeyboard.add_line()
vkkeyboard.add_button("Картошка!", color='secondary')

...

      if len(existcheck) > 0:
          write_msg(event.user_id, "Вы уже зарегистрировались", vkkeyboard)
```

Comment: спасибо, работает!

Comment: @likel0vsky, пожалуйста :)